# Seeking partition management advice to allow dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I would like to dual boot Ubuntu with the already installed Windows 7. I have enough space on my hard drive for Ubuntu, but I have four primary partitions already factory made in my computer. This means something has to give and being fairly new, I don't know all of the details of what each of the drives do and I don't want to mess things up. I don't even know if I can actually do any these things, but I am wondering if I can:

- Delete one of my existing partitions (putting it in a DVD in case I need the recovery tools)
- Change one of the partitions to be an extended partition
- Any other option that will allow me to keep Windows and the recovery tools

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite C650D-02Q

The partitions are

[unnamed] 1.46 GB

[C:] 396.40 GB (i shrank it to make room for the partition i cant make)

39.06 unallocated

[unnamed] 18.15 GB (my best guess as to what is is, is recovery tools)

[unnamed] 10.68 GB (again don't really know what this one is)

I am really looking for any solution that will allow me to safely dual boot W7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: You should delete one partition, also, you sure the all are unnamed and with those weird sizes? Attach a GParted screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop when it was new, I copied the data from one of the smaller recovery partitions ( preferrably the manufactures recovery which has all their bloat wear and what not on it,) copy it in to Windows and delete the partition then recreate an extended partition using the remaining space and create your desired partitions to run Ubuntu.